# ReactJS Redux dispatch called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an action that transfers the index of the card when I click on it and a window opens with the settings of this card. A window with settings opens, this window has a button that should close the window (changing cardIndex to null), however, when the "closeWindow" action is triggered, changing the cardIndex state to null and immediately sets the cardIndex state with a previous index. I'm new in ReactJS and Redux, what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

My code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchCalendar, handleCalendarIndex } from "../../actions/calendarActions";
const CalendarCard = ({getCalendarData, loading, calendarCard, cardIndex, openWindow, closeWindow}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getCalendarData()
    },[getCalendarData]);
    const renderCalendarCard = () => {
        if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
        if (calendarCard !== null) return (<div className="calendar-container">
            {calendarCard.calendar_results.map((dateCard, dateIndex) => {
                const dateResults = calcPositions(dateCard);
                return(
                <div className="day-card" key={dateCard.checkin} onClick={() => openWindow(dateIndex)}>
                    {
                        cardIndex ?
                            <div className="day-details">
                                <span className="close-modal"
                                onClick={() => closeWindow()}>x</span>
                                <h3>Current date details</h3>
                            </div> :
                        null
                    }
                    <div className="card-header">
                        <div className="current-date">
                            <span className="date-name">{handleDate(dateCard.checkin)}</span>
                            <span className="day-name">{getDayName(dateCard.checkin)}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="available-count">
                            <span className='text-value'>{dateCard.available_listings_ng}
                                ({dateCard.available_listings_ratio_ng.toFixed(0)}%)</span>
                              <span className='text-label'>Av. lists</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )})}
        </div>);
        return <p>error</p>;

    };
    return (
        <section>
            <h1>Calendar card</h1>
            {renderCalendarCard()}
        </section>
    )
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getCalendarData: () => dispatch(fetchCalendar('4c5c752f-c9d2-42d0-9f00-2fc0b11989a5')),
    openWindow: cardIndex => dispatch(handleCalendarIndex(cardIndex)),
    closeWindow: () => dispatch(handleCalendarIndex(null))
  }
};


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.calendarCard.loading,
  calendarCard: state.calendarCard.calendarCard,
  hasErrors: state.calendarCard.hasErrors,
  cardIndex: state.calendarCard.cardIndex
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CalendarCard)
```

my handleCalendarIndex function

```
export function handleCalendarIndex(calendarIndex) {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(changeCalendarIndex(calendarIndex))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for the `handleCalendarIndex` action?

Comment: added to main post

Comment: Thanks, now can you please show the `changeCalendarIndex` function? I need to see the full trail to try to see what's happening.

Comment: export const changeCalendarIndex = cardIndex => ({
    type: CHANGE_CARD_INDEX,
    newIndex: cardIndex
});